# Change / rearrange / move user properties - Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile, user-profile-property, properties

Is there a way with PowerShell to rearrange / change the order of user properties? If I create a custom user property and make it visible on the mysite I have to click like 100 times to get in to the "basic information" tab. How can I change the order with PowerShell?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer..

```
$MySite = Get-SPSite "$site"
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $MySite
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

$profilemanager.properties | ft name,displayorder

$profileManager.Properties.SetDisplayOrderByPropertyName(“userpropertyname”,1)
$profileManager.Properties.CommitDisplayOrder()
```

[moving user properties](http://www.sharepointfire.com/MyBlog/2014/02/moving-user-properties-up-in-sharepoint-with-powershell/)